# Edit Files on Virtual Machines of Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, console, ide, virtual-machine

What is the best way to edit files on Virtual Machines of Google Cloud?
Do I have to use console to update files?

ide.cloud.google.com is a good tool to modify files with its editor.
Is there a way to use it to access and modify files on Virtual Machines of Google Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to edit files on a GCE VM is to use Cloud Shell plus the `gcloud` too.

1. [Open Cloud Shell](https://shell.cloud.google.com/?hl=en_US&fromcloudshell=true&show=terminal) in your browser
2. [SSH](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) into the VM you want to work on `gcloud compute ssh <VM-name> --zone <VM-zone>`
3. Edit the files using `nano`, `vi`, or other tools

If you want to edit the files in a text editor, you can do that by

1. Opening the Cloud editor from Cloud Shell (see icon below)
2. Edit your files locally
3. [SCP](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) files to your VM using `gcloud compute scp <local-file> <VM-name>: --zone <VM-zone>`

[image]